# Downloading MS SQL Server 2008 Standard edition

Tags: sql-server

I want to download MS SQL Server 2008 with business intellegence standard edition. But I don't know how to download it, because the one I got was EXPRESS edition and everytime I run the x86 FULL 2008 server standard I downloaded, which is 1.3 GB in size, I cannot install it. It keeps telling me to run the setup.exe file but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

MS SQL 2008 Standard is a retail product for purchase.  Do you have Technet or Actionpack?  If not, where are you downloading this from?  Sounds like you are downloading the Express (free) version.

Comment: i tried to get it from technet microsoft, but its not working

Comment: Contact TechNet support, that's what you're paying for.